# R: plotting title and abline for multiple plots generated with lapply

Tags: r, lapply

I am generating multiple plots using `lapply` to retrieve data from a vector for each of the plots.

Problem:

- I need to plot the `abline` for each graph, but it plots only in the last one.
- Ideally, I would also plot a different title for each of the graphs.

Data:

- `perfs` is a vector with 3 elements and each of its elements contains the main data for the plot.
- Each item in perfs corresponds to a value of `k`, that has been previously defined in the vector `ks = c(5,7,11)`

I have tried adding arguments to lapply.

```
   lapply(perfs, function(perf) {plot(perf, main = paste0("Curva ROC", ks), col = "#42f4bf", lwd = 4)})
   abline(a = 0, b = 1, lwd = 2, lty = 2)
```

Actual:

- `abline` only in the last plot.
- The title repeated for each of the `k` in every plot: `ROC Curve5 ROC Curve7...`
- This is the last plot:
  [image: roc_curve_wrong]

Expected:

- Title: ROC Curve 5 ; ROC Curve 7...
- `abline` in each graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the **correct title** for each plot, you'll need to have a way of linking the elements of perfs to the elements of ks so you can just select the one you need for each plot.
One way to do this (perhaps the simplest) would be to use a `for` loop, rather than lapply, and use `ks[i]` in the `main` parameter of `plot`. If you prefer to use `lapply`, then I think `match` should work fine (as in my code below), provided each of the elements of `perfs` are different.

To have an `abline` **for each plot**, you'll need to include the `abline` part within the function you call in `lapply`, so that you run that part alongside each plot.

```
lapply(perfs, function(perf) {
  k <- ks[match(list(perf), perfs)]     # Only need list() is perfs is a list
  plot(perf, main = paste0("Curve ROC", k), col = "#42f4bf", lwd = 4)
  abline(a = 0, b = 1, lwd = 2, lty = 2)
})
```

Comment: I tried this ```lapply(perfs, function(perf) {plot(perf, main = paste0("ROC Curve"), col = "#42f4bf", lwd = 4) abline(a = 0, b = 1, lwd = 2, lty = 2)})``` 
and I got this error: ```Error: unexpected symbol in "lapply(perfs, function(perf) {plot(perf, main = paste0("ROC Curve"), col = "#42f4bf", lwd = 4) abline"```

Comment: I got a similar error when I included k as you worte

Comment: I came up with a solution following the ```for loop``` advice

Comment: @bertagp I only get an 'unexpected symbol' error if I don't have a line break between plot and abline within my lapply function - otherwise, I'm unsure why you're getting that error. I edited the part of my answer where k is selected slightly, in case perfs is a list. I'm glad you found the 'for' comment helpful, and seem to have found a solution to your problem.

Comment: @hodgenovide thank you! I was not adding the line break

Answer (score 0):

I am using a for loop as sugested by @hodgenovice

I use an index `ind` to access the values of `k` in the `ks` vector.
This way I can plot the `abline` for each graph and also name them according to the value of `k`.

```
ks <-c(5, 7, 11) # the previously defined values of k

ind <- 1 # index used for accessing ks
for (perf in perfs){  # each perf in perfs contains data used in the plot
     k <- ks[ind]
     ind <- ind + 1
     plot(perf, main = paste0("ROC Curve k = ", k), col = "#42f4bf", lwd = 4) 
     abline(a = 0, b = 1, lwd = 2, lty = 2)
}
```